# How to install tatar language?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I want to use [tatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatar_language) language on my machine. Specifically, I need a tatar keyboard layout. How do I set it?

I didn't find any ubuntu packages for the language, only for crimean tatar which is not suitable because it's writing is not cyrillic.

Comment: Did you try going to [Settings > Regional & Language > + > search and Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLgVK.png)?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?